# 74LS pull line low in-circuit

Tags: digital-logic, 7400

I am working on repairing a TRS-80 Model 4P and would like to test to see if a buffer is working. The problem is the line keeps being held high and I would like to pull it low to see if it is working. Can I/what resistor could I use to pull the line low temporarily(few seconds)?

Comment: Which line, and what part number is the buffer chip?

Comment: What is pulling it high? If it is a resistor, then OK, but if it is coming from another IC then forcing it low could possible cause more damage. TTL low has to be below 0.8V. 1kohm should do it if the signal is floating, but if it is activly driven high then you need to overcome the driver.